# Reveal fields if needed

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I'm trying to make a contact-form in php. You can find it [here](http://thoelen.nl/suskewiet/index.php?page=contact).

I try to make the textbox with datepicker invisible until the visitor checks the radiobutton "ja", only then it needs to be visible.

Here's the code for the form:

```js
var FormStuff = {

  init: function() {
    this.applyConditionalRequired();
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  bindUIActions: function() {
    $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").on("change", this.applyConditionalRequired);
  },

  applyConditionalRequired: function() {

    $(".require-if-active").each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      if ($(el.data("require-pair")).is(":checked")) {
        el.prop("required", true);
      } else {
        el.prop("required", false);
      }
    });

  }

};

FormStuff.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
  <!--< ?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>-->
  <table id="contactForm">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Reservatie: </label></td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="nospacing"><input type="radio" name="reservatie" value="Ja" id="ja"></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><label for="reservatie">Ja</label></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><input type="radio" name="reservatie" value="Nee" id="nee"></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><label for="reservatie">Nee</label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <div class="reveal-if-active">
        <tr>
          <td><label for="reservering">Reserveringsdatum: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="reservering" autocomplete="off" name="reservering" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#ja"></td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden" /></td>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Formulier wissen" class="alt" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `$()` references require jQuery

Comment: there's no code here to make anything visible or invisible, so that might be your mistake. There's code to make fields required or not, but that's not the same as visible. And your snippet is missing jQuery, don't know if that's the case for your real code or not.

Comment: Speaking of mistakes, let's just say your code is too complicated for its purpose. You could just make the datepicker hidden unless Ja is chosen in a single function modifying its attributes

Comment: And as ADyson said, `required` is an attribute that doesn't let you submit the form unless all the required fields have an input, while `hidden` is an attribute that doesn't show the user whatever is in the tag that has that attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){})` to detect you input change see code snippet.

```js
var FormStuff = {

  init: function() {
    this.applyConditionalRequired();
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  bindUIActions: function() {
    $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").on("change", this.applyConditionalRequired);
  },

  applyConditionalRequired: function() {

    $(".require-if-active").each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      if ($(el.data("require-pair")).is(":checked")) {
        el.prop("required", true);
      } else {
        el.prop("required", false);
      }
    });

  }

};

FormStuff.init();
 /* this is the function to handle you need */
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($('input[type="radio"]#ja').is(':checked'))
    {
      $(".reveal-if-active").show();
    }
    else if('input[type="radio"]#nee'){
     $(".reveal-if-active").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
  <!--< ?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>-->
  <table id="contactForm">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Reservatie: </label></td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="nospacing"><input type="radio" name="reservatie" value="Ja" id="ja"></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><label for="reservatie">Ja</label></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><input type="radio" name="reservatie" value="Nee" id="nee"></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><label for="reservatie">Nee</label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <div >
        <!-- make the tr the element to hide and show -->
        <tr class="reveal-if-active" style="display:none">
          <td  ><label for="reservering">Reserveringsdatum: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="reservering"  autocomplete="off" name="reservering" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#ja"></td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden" /></td>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Formulier wissen" class="alt" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your markup is kinda messed up:

You shouldn't mix **div** tags with **tr**, only **tr** tags should be present on the same 'level' of nesting in **table** tag

Secondly, answering you actual question - add click event listeners on the radiobuttons, so that when YES is clicked, you make visible your "reveal-if-active" row:

```
var inputToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("reveal-if-active")[0];
var jaInput = document.getElementById("ja");
var neeInput = document.getElementById("nee");

function makeInputVisibleAgain() {
    inputToHide.style.display = "block";
}

function hideInput() {
    inputToHide.style.display = "none";
}

jaInput.addEventListener("click", makeInputVisibleAgain);
neeInput.addEventListener("click", hideInput);
```

Thirdly - don't use several ids with same name, better change your **id="nospacing"** to class

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you want something like this? Notice that it's very easy to do it in very few lines of code. Since you're a beginner I'll explain:

`$( ... );` is jQuery's way to say "when the page is totally loaded, start executing what's inside". In case you didn't know, without this the scripts would start executing any time and could cause errors, mainly because of not finding the elements you work with.

`$('input[name="reservatie"]').change(function(){ ... });`: the radio buttons have name "reservatie", so when they are changed it will execute the function inside `change()`.

`$('#reveal').prop('hidden', !$('#ja').prop('checked'));`: I identified the row of the table where the datepicker was as "reveal", because, maybe I'm wrong, but putting one row of it inside of a div didn't let my code go well, so I believe that was just wrong. I deleted the div and used the row instead. So, its attribute `hidden` will be the opposite of the checked property of "ja", which means, if "ja" is checked, the datepicker won't be hidden, and if it's not, it will.

Hope it helps you.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[name="reservatie"]').change(function(){
    $('#reveal').prop('hidden', !$('#ja').prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
  <!--< ?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>-->
  <table id="contactForm">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Reservatie: </label></td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="nospacing"><input type="radio" name="reservatie" value="Ja" id="ja"></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><label for="reservatie">Ja</label></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><input type="radio" name="reservatie" value="Nee" id="nee"></td>
              <td id="nospacing"><label for="reservatie">Nee</label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

      </tr>
        <tr id="reveal" hidden>
          <td><label for="reservering">Reserveringsdatum: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="reservering" autocomplete="off" name="reservering" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#ja"></td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden" /></td>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Formulier wissen" class="alt" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```